# if statement is executing,else-if statements are not in java

Tags: if-statement, drop-down-menu

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class sam{
    public static void main(String[]args){

    String a;
    String b;
    int c;

    sam s1 = new sam();

    a=s1.getInfo();
    c=s1.getBalance();
    b=s1.getMenu(a,c);

    }
```

//menu method starts here

```
    public String getMenu (String c, Integer d) {
String[] a;
String[] choices = { "Account Balance", "Deposit", "Withdraw", "User Account", "Exit options"};
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What would you like to do?",
    "ATM menu", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,choices,choices[0]);

if  ((choices[0] == choices[0])){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Account Balance is: "+d,"ATM machine",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
```

//the if statement is executing properly

```
 else if    ((choices[1] == choices[1])){
    String in=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deposit: ");
    int deposit=Integer.parseInt(in);
    int add=d+deposit;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Current Balance: "+add,"ATM machine",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
```

//but when I chose account balance it displays the if statement not the else-if one

```
 else if    ((choices[2] == choices[2])){
    String in=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Withdraw: ");
    int withdraw=Integer.parseInt(in);
    int sub=d+withdraw;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Current Balance: "+sub,"ATM machine",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}

 else if    ((choices[3] == choices[3])){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," "+c,"ATM machine",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}

 else if    ((choices[4] == choices[4])){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The program will be terminated in a few seconds","ATM machine",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
 }
 return input;
  }
```

//I'm quite new to programming, I rushed coded it for finals.

Comment: I think you missed the point of `if` and `else if` clauses... Actually all of your conditions will always evaluate to true (they're all the same thing as `if 1 == 1`), but as your code passes in the first `if` , it will simply pass over the next `else if` statements. You can't do  both the `if` and the `else if` instructions.

Comment: Thanks it helped me realize it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your `if` statements will evaluate to `true`. I think your intentions were to compare `String c` with each of the `Strings` in the `choices` array.

When comparing `Strings` always use `.equals()` not `==`.

Example:

```
if (c.equals(choices[0])) {
    // code
} else if (c.equals(choices[1])) {
    //code
} else if (c.equals(choices[2])) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot. I'm still confused on how to use if statements that's why I don't usually use them to code in hands on projects.

Comment: If statements are one of the most important concepts in programming, it's worth spending some time to get your head around them :). If this answered your question, don't forget to mark as the accepted answer.